# How do I parse parameters in spray routing containing operators other than "="?

Tags: scala, spray

How do I parse parameters in spray routing containing operators other than `=`?

For example, consider:

```
http://example.com?a=xyz&b<12 ?
```

Here two query parameters are present. One is `a=xyz` and the other one is `b<12`.

I would like to know if there is any way to extract `b<12` in `parametermap` in spray routing, since it takes only those parameters containing `=` operator?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`parameterMap` directive](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameterMap/) and extract it from the key:

```
val route = path("test") {
  get {
    parameterMap { 
      map: Map[String, String] =>
        // Extract elements from map
    }
  }
}
```

Note that your key will appear as `b<13` with an empty string as a value, so you'll need to extract the key and parse it manually.